# Is it that if we solve any first degree variable equations, we'll get a straight line on the coordinate plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

If we solve any first degree variable equation will we always get a straight line on the coordinate plane? Is it because of this property we call these types of equations linear equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by first degree you restrict to two variables, say $x,y,$ and not both coefficients of them zero, then yes always get a line, and conversely any line in plane has such an equation. With more variables (again not all coeffs zero) get an affine subset of dimension one less than number of vars, sometimes called a hyperplane (and conversely a hyperplane has such an equation).